# setting homepage in IIS for mvc4 website /application (no forms no.aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, start-page

as it happens i had a long day solving settings problems and now that i am set with mvc4 (moved from WebForms) and vs2010 .

after deploying to  IIS(7 v7.5) i could not make the project load unless i specify the full path to the view . besides putting a static html or aspx page

how is it possible to make it redirect to [MyFirstControl]/[MyFirstView]

is it missing a master ? is it the issue between selecting a Website vs WebApplication ?

i have connected my Ip to a domain name, opened ports in FW for iis , and all i want is to be able to enter the site / application through its domain name rather having to dial in the control + view .
so what do i need to do?

by the way i am using basic template as i want minimal volume of code 
and is it a website by definition or web-application does it actually matter as programmer in  .NET no website is a website but an application as you never just put html but a business layer and db.. but i don't understand the differences on the names /terms

Edit

i have googled for long time trying to get it right

```
 <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only registered a single route (the default that is created in a new MVC project):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The `defaults` argument provides default values when there is no action or no controller in the URL. So when you navigate to the root (`/`) then the `Index` action is executed on the `HomeController`.

Apparently, you want the root (`/`) to point to the `MyFirstView` action on the `MyFirstControl` controller so in principle you simply have to change the value of the `defaults` argument. However, your controller class ends with `Control` but MVC expects it to end with `Controller` so you have to rename your controller class to `MyFirstController` and then configure this default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyFirst", action = "MyFirstView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also, using `View` in an action name is somewhat confusing.

Routing in ASP.NET is a very important concept and you can learn more about it by reading the article [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i was too busy to notes that after troubleshooting issues around all the required settings, i forgot to make sure i reset all my tests on renaming the control from index to home and my view from default to index or so somehow in the code above only when i added the edit. i took a last look just to make sure, but it turns it was my mistake so i leave it for future reference so others will learn from this mistake.